# Sum up duplicate values in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'd appreciate your help in modifying the code below:

```
Public Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Call Sheet1.CommandButton1_Click
Sheet8.Activate

'101-WP-101
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("T19:T30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("B12")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("E19:E30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("C12")
'101-WP-102
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("U19:U30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("E12")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("F19:F30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("F12")
'101-WP-103
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("V19:V30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("H12")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("G19:G30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("I12")
'101-WP-104
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("W19:W30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("B27")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("H19:H30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("C27")
'101-WP-105
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("X19:X30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("E27")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("I19:I30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("F27")
'102-WP-101
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("Y19:Y30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("B43")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("J19:J30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("C43")
'102-WP-102
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("Z19:Z30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("E43")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("K19:K30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("F43")
'102-WP-103
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("AA19:AA30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("H43")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("L19:L30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("I43")
'102-WP-104
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("AB19:AB30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("B58")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("M19:M30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("C58")
'102-WP-105
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("AC19:AC30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("E58")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("N19:N30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("F58")
'102-WP-106
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("AD19:AD30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("H58")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("O19:O30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("I58")
'102-WP-107
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("AE19:AE30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("B73")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("P19:P30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("C73")
'102-WP-108
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("AF19:AF30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("E73")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("Q19:Q30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("F73")
'102-WP-109
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("AG19:AG30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("H73")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("R19:R30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("I73")
'102-WP-110
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("AH19:AH30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("B88")
Sheets("Data Normalize").Range("S19:S30").Copy Destination:=Sheets("summary").Range("C88")

Call SumDuplicates(12, 2)
Call SumDuplicates(12, 5)
Call SumDuplicates(12, 8)
Call SumDuplicates(27, 2)
Call SumDuplicates(27, 5)
Call SumDuplicates(43, 2)
Call SumDuplicates(43, 5)
Call SumDuplicates(43, 8)
Call SumDuplicates(58, 2)
Call SumDuplicates(58, 5)
Call SumDuplicates(58, 8)
Call SumDuplicates(73, 2)
Call SumDuplicates(73, 5)
Call SumDuplicates(73, 8)
Call SumDuplicates(88, 2)

End Sub
```

And then:

```
Private Function SumDuplicates(startRow As Integer, startCol As Integer)
Dim lngRow As Long

With ActiveSheet

    lngRow = .Cells(startRow, startCol).End(xlDown).Row

    .Cells(startRow, startCol).CurrentRegion.sort key1:=.Cells(startRow, startCol), Header:=xlYes 'change this to xlYes if your table has header cells
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = lngRow

   Do

       If .Cells(lngRow - 1, startCol) = .Cells(lngRow, startCol) Then
          .Cells(lngRow - 1, startCol + 1) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, startCol + 1) + .Cells(lngRow, startCol + 1)
          .Cells(lngRow, startCol).Clear
          .Cells(lngRow, startCol + 1).Clear

      End If

      lngRow = lngRow - 1

   Loop Until lngRow < (startRow + 1)

End With

End Function
```

When I run the code, it is stopping on the text highlighted/underline in red (the first line below).

```
.Cells(startRow, startCol).CurrentRegion.sort key1:=.Cells(startRow, startCol), Header:=xlYes 'change this to xlYes if your table has header cells
.Cells(1, 1).Value = lngRow
```

What is missing..on my code
I have multiple tables in my worksheet.

Comment: What error message is it giving you?

Comment: It's difficult to help you unless you tell us what the problem is... Is there an error? If so, what is the error message? And what is the value of *each* variable in the statement which raises the error?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have

```
Sheets("summary").Activate
```

before you start on your calls to SumDuplicates

```
'switch to summary sheet
Sheets("summary").Activate
Call SumDuplicates(12, 2)
```

etc.